# Getting facebook fans count without API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the number of fans of a facebook page in simple text without using facebook API? I have been searching on google, but none of them works, which can be because of change in facebook api.
I don't want to include the api because i want to add that piece of code in a theme, which will be used by multiple people.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Graph API is very easy to use and you dont need any authentication so I really can't see any reason not to use it.

Just do a simple HTTP get to the follow URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/norwegianmafia

(replace "norwegianmafia" with your page name)

You could also easily use this method in jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/norwegianmafia?callback=?", function(data) { 
alert("Likes: " + data.likes); 
});
```

Comment: hm true didn't see that, but I guess fans=likes?

Answer (score 2):

Followed, above steps earlier, it worked. Offlate it keeps throwing an error use access token.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "AN1JLj+DAks"
   }
}
```